# Django 500 message in custom template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a 500.html template which gets loaded whenever my app explodes but I wanted to know if there's any way I can output the exception's message in the template?

So if I do this:

```
raise Exception("You broke it!")
```

This will load 500.html when the DEBUG flag is set to True but how can I access the exception message in the template? Something like:

```
{{ exception.message }}
```

Many thanks.

G

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look at this answer:

[How do I include a stacktrace in my Django 500.html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121439/how-do-i-include-a-stacktrace-in-my-django-500-html-page)

It's not good to pass the exception to your template/user as it might show some inside workings that you don't want available to the outside, but if you really need to, you could write your own 500 view, grabbing the exception and passing it to your 500 template

**views.py**

```
def custom_500(request):
    t = loader.get_template('500.html')
    type, value, tb = sys.exc_info(),
    return HttpResponseServerError(t.render(Context({
    'exception_value': value,
})))
```

somewhere in **urls.py**

```
handler500 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_error_view'
```

**template**

```
{{ exception_value }}
```

more about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view

Comment: Good answer. As @pastylegs mentions this is definitely *not* a good idea. You might as well just set DEBUG to True in your production environment; it's even easier than this method. I'd recommend using django-sentry, instead of doing this. You'll get the info you want when a server error occurs, but behind lock-and-key, where it belongs.

Comment: django-sentry is a very good idea. It also has the added feature that you can pass a error-token to your 500 template which is linked to the stacktrace/error in the sentry backend. This means your user can submit an error report with this token and you can track down the actual error without letting them see any gobble-de-gook

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but I just wanna to make it clear:

The answer is correct if you want a custon view! The default view will load a 500.html (also 404.html and others), from the main templates directory of your project if it's there.

So, if all you need is to change static page content, like insert some images in your error page, all you have to do is to create a template file at this place.