# Django how to redirect python import error to custom error page

Tags: python, django

I need to redirect django 'import error' to a custom error page.All other errors except import error is redrecting to custom error page

Already in DEBUG= False
Error displayed in browser is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 283, in run
  self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
  response = self.get_response(request)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
 response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 214, in handle_uncaught_exception
if resolver.urlconf_module is None:

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 274, in _get_urlconf_module
self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in   import_module
  __import__(name)

File "/project/backup/project/hg/rel0129/hg/src/customer_/../customer_/hg/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
from lostpassword.views import recaptcha, reset

File "/project/backup/project/hg/rel0129/hg/../customer_/hg/lostpassword/views.py", line 12, in <module>
from hg.utils.common import __render, __redirect
hg/utils/common.py", line 15, in <module>
from urllibwrapper import URLClient, ClientResponse

 ImportError: No module named urlwrapper
```

The error needs to be redirect to custom error page

Thanks in advance

Comment: `404` is for page not found. Ideally you want `500` (or Server Error). Why do you specify a `404`?

Comment: I mean custom error page or django default error template.

Comment: An import exception is a programming error, not a 'correct server, wrong URL, sorry!' error.

Comment: If the server is not running in debug mode you are already being sent a 500 error page.

Comment: I dont want to correct this error need to show an error template when this error occurs..

Comment: @MartijnPieters No its not being sent to 500 error page...

Comment: @tomjoy: It will already show you an error page. The error page differs when you have `DEBUG` set to `True`, however. The 500 error page is only enabled when `DEBUG` is `False`.

Comment: Already in DEBUG is False.But not redirecting..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django will **already** show you an error page when there is an import error; what error page is shown depends on the value of `DEBUG`.

If `DEBUG` is set to `True`, you are shown the traceback and some debug information.

If `DEBUG` is `False`, Django shows you the default 500 error page. You can set a custom 500 error response by either providing a `500.html` page in the root of your templates directory, or by providing a `handler500` string in your root URLConf.

See the [500 error view documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/views/#the-500-server-error-view).

However, an import error in your project can prevent Django from being configured correctly, and the custom 500 error handler won't be found. There is such a thing as 'too broken', and an early import exception is such a situation. The exception then bypasses the Django error handling altogether and drops down to the WSGI server level instead.

In such a situation, *provided `DEBUG` is set to `False`*, the user is shown the default 500 error message, a simple text message:

> A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

Note that *older* Django releases (prior to 1.4) the built-in server can still show the traceback of import exceptions even when debug mode is off, because these older versions use their own simple HTTP server.

You can upgrade your Django server to 1.4 or newer in that case, and / or not use the built-in server. Use a proper [production deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/deployment/) instead.

Comment: @tomjoy: Two possibilities: the import error is preventing Django from completing configuration of your project (so it doesn't know about the template root, and won't find the `500.html` page), or you have DEBUG set to True.

Comment: @tomjoy: The import error is rather severe, you cannot hope to deploy a site to production when it is *that* broken.

Comment: Any solution to avoid displaying a user with import error page and displays a custom error page?

Comment: @tomjoy: Not deploy a server that is fundamentally broken? If `DEBUG` is set to `False`, the end user is **not** shown an import error.

Comment: But on  deployment am  not able to see any error with configuration.

Comment: @tomjoy: If you see the traceback view (`ImportError at ...`, etc.), then `DEBUG` is set to `True`.

Comment: In settings.py DEBUG = False,
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG,
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47014/discussion-between-martijn-pieters-and-tom-joy)

Answer (score 1):

To raise a custom error page you need to define a template and then add the following into your `urls.py`:

```
handler500 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_error_view'
```

To see more (including the traceback - NOT recommended if `DEBUG = False`) have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190438/1401034) to [Django 500 message in custom template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190254/django-500-message-in-custom-template).

More information in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view).

> This server_error view should suffice for 99% of Web applications, but if you want to override the view, you can specify handler500 in your root URLconf, like so:
>
> `handler500 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_error_view'`
>
> Behind the scenes, Django determines the `500` view by looking for `handler500` in your root URLconf, and falling back to `django.views.defaults.server_error` if you did not define one.
>
> One thing to note about `500` views:
>
> If `DEBUG` is set to `True` (in your settings module), then your `500` view will never be used, and the traceback will be displayed instead, with some debug information.